# Is that true what native English speakers are using more sentence form like "How/Wh~ does/ do /did"?

Tags: american-english

I have a question about how does native English speakers more use proper question sentence form?

for example,

## 1. What is meaning ~

## 2. What does mean ~

So I am curious about which of the following sentence is more used in native English speaker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. An English speaker would ask, "What is the meaning of ____?" For example, "What is the meaning of 'cricket'?"
2. An English speaker would ask, "What do (or does) ____ mean? For example, "What does 'don't put the cart before the horse' mean?"

Both forms are common and correct.

Comment: Er, it should be noted that "What is the meaning of ___?", while grammatically correct, is typically used as an interjection, and not a question. I, as an American, have never heard anyone use that sentence form to ask an actual question about, for instance, the meaning of a word. You might be familiar with the common sentence, "What is the meaning of this!" which means "This is outrageous; why are you doing this?"

Comment: @CrazyEyes: I agree the second form, "What do (or does) ___ mean?" is more common, and is the form I would use.

Comment: ngram suggests that "what is the meaning of _" and "what is the meaning of this" are almost equally common phrases, suggesting very strongly that the "what is the meaning of _ " use is almost entirely specialised to the interjection "what is the meaning of this?" implying as @CrazyEyes says a sense of outrage. They are certainly *not* to be treated as similar in British English. The first usage is marked and distinct. If you want to know what something means, use 2.

Comment: "What is the meaning of life" is another example usage of the first form, specialised to philosophical meaning. If I heard "What is the meaning of cricket?" I would assume someone was asking for something philosophical rather than a definition of cricket. In British English that is a more likely question anyway :-).